# Counting word occurrences in vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, vector

I got this homework assignment in which I have to make a c++ application that can be called from cmd with parameters. There are 3 parameters:

The first one takes all words without punctuations, converts them to lower and stores them alphabetically. So I used a vector string.

The second one counts occurrences of each word in the file and sorts them so the most used word is first. I'm stuck at this part and dunno how to handle this.. so if anyone can help me I would be very grateful

The third parameter counts occurrences of each punctuation..same as above and as you can figure, I'm also stuck at this part haha
This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
ifstream ulaz ("korpus.txt");
string testline;
vector<string> word;

if (string(argv[1])=="-r"){
    cout<<"uzima rijeci iz korpusa i stavlja u rijecnik po abecedi"<<endl;
    while(ulaz >> testline)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<testline.size(); i++){
                if (ispunct(testline[i])) testline.erase(i);
        }
    transform (testline.begin(), testline.end(), testline.begin(), ::tolower);
    word.push_back(testline);
    }
    sort(word.begin(), word.end());
    for (int i=0; i<word.size(); i++) {
            cout<<word[i]<<"("<<i<<")"<<endl;
    }
}


if (string(argv[1])=="-f"){
    cout<<endl<<"frekventonost ponavljanja se izračunava"<<endl;
}
if (string(argv[1])=="-i"){
    cout<<endl<<"broj interpunkcija i sranja se izračunava"<<endl;

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even the part you've got doesn't work if you have two successive punctuation, e.g. `word!"`.  And of course, your use of `ispunct` and `::tolower` is undefined behavior; calling them with a `char` is undefined behavior on most implementations, unless you've done some range checking first.  What's wrong with the standard idiom: `testline.erase( std::remove_if( testline.begin(), testline.end(), []( unsigned char ch ) { return ::ispunct( ch ); } ), testline.end() );` for removing punctuation?

Comment: I just tested it out, it removes successive punctuations. I would use the idiom you posted, but I just don't understand it. Also Is there a better way to put it tolower then?

Comment: is this better for putting text to lower?
for(int i=0; i<testline.size(); i++){
                    if (ispunct(testline[i])) testline.erase(i);
                    if (isupper(testline[i])) testline[i]=tolower(testline[i]);
            }Is this better for putting letters to lowercase?

Comment: You haven't tested your code well.  There are two problems with your loop to remove punctuation.  The first is that the second argument of `std::string::erase` defaults to `npos`, so you erase everything from that point to the end of the string: `"wasn't"` becomes `"wasn"`, and not `"wasnt"`.  The second is that when you correct this, and use `testline.erase( i, 1 );`, you don't test the character which is shifted down into the position after the erase.  As for not understanding my suggestion: it is the idiomatic way of doing this in C++, so you should have no trouble finding explinations.

Comment: And as I said, you cannot call any of the functions in `<ctype.h>` with a `char`.  It will work for some characters, but not for others.

Comment: To be clearer, for the code you've got try the word `"abc!!xyz"`.  You should get `"abcxyz"`; you won't.  And you might want to try `tolower( 'Č' )`, just to see what happens.  (It's undefined behavior: it might work, or it might not.  Of course, if you're using UTF-8 encoding, `'Č'` might not even compile, since the character requires two bytes.)

Comment: So I kinda got that remove_if function, but the compiler gives me this error: "no matching function for call to 'remove_if" Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a words counter using map or unordered_map:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> counter;
for (auto w : word)
{
    counter[w]++;
}
```

Then you need only sort elements of the map by count.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain this foreach? I don't get it :S

Comment: @Loki It's something he's invented, or taken from some other language.  There's no keyword `foreach` in C++.

Comment: hahhahahah damn i thought so, but the first line was right so I was confused, but I got it working so it's fine now

Comment: How can you sort the map by count? From what I know you can only sort the map by key not by value. In your example The counter is by value. You'll have to convert it to pair or use a very hard combination